# Android Connecting to Network Example gives me IOException

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I was trying to implement Android's example of connecting to a http client to receive data.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

I would like to implement something like this so that my Android app can connect to a php webservice to get a result from the webpage.

The problem here is that the method "checkMemberExists(urls[0])" keeps giving me an IOException and thus, the program quits and does not go into the onPostExecute(..). 
I have tried to implement as close to the example in the above link. But can't understand why it does not work for me. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
private class DbCheckMemberExistsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {

            String strContentString = checkMemberExists(urls[0]);

            return strContentString;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        memberExists.setText(result);
   }


    public String checkMemberExists(String email) throws IOException 
    {

        //returns 0 : does not exists
        //returns 1 : exists but not activated
        //returns 2 : exists and activated

        InputStream is = null;
        int len = 500;

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(strDatabaseWebService+"checkmemberexists.php?email="+email);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("log_debug", "The response is: " + response);
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
            Log.d("log_debug", "The response is: " + contentAsString);




            //return contentAsString;
            return contentAsString;

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return "9";
        }
        finally 
        {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }           
        }   

    }

    // Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.
    public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Reader reader = null;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");        
        char[] buffer = new char[len];
        reader.read(buffer);
        return new String(buffer);
    }       

}
```

Comment: Please visit this . I hope it will help you to find your issues.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600239/communicate-between-android-application-and-java/18670004#18670004

Answer (score 0):

check to see if you have the internet permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />.
```

Check if the URL is formated correctly by printing it out to your log.
Specifically what "strDatabaseWebService+"checkmemberexists.php?email="+email" resolved to.

Also, if you can post your log it may help to see what is going wrong.

EDIT:

I am using a similar code as this one in a "doInBackground()". The problems I had when developing this, were related to the HttpURLConnection implementation. Apparently is has some issues to reuse connections when "keepalive" is active. There are plenty posts abouth this in SO.
You can try to see if any of this helps you resolve the problem.

```
    try{
        //(1) This has to do with something not working properly in the HttpURLConnection class and how it reuses connections
        //So the advice is to close each connection after using it.
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        URL url;
        url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592510/android-connecting-to-network-example-gives-me-ioexception/23592876?noredirect=1#comment36228428_23592876");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        //(2) The seme as (1)
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

        //(3) Dirty workaround when reading a lot of files one after another, I randomly get some strange values.
        //You can try not using the "sleep", but I thougt of including it because I understood you read many files one after another one.
        try{
            Thread.sleep(200);
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Ignore this, not a big deal
        }

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        int c = is.read();
        while (c!= -1){
            sb.append((char) c);
            c = is.read();
        }

        is.close();
        conn.disconnect();
        return sb.toString();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have placed the user permissions in the android manifest. Also, the URL is correct as I can fetch the data into the InputStream and view the data in the IDE. Still the same problem. Appreciate your help.