# client server application over wifi using an access point

Tags: android, websocket, socket.io

I am building a simple client server application on which both client and server will connect to an access point, lets assume d-link router, and after successful connection client should be able to send a message and server should be able to show it on the screen. So, can anybody give me some ideas about how should I implement this idea?

Comment: I hope this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600239/communicate-between-android-application-and-java/18670004#18670004 will help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600239/communicate-between-android-application-and-java/18670004#18670004

Comment: @BlueGreen thanks for such a quick reply and sorry for not mentioning my task clearly. i saw these two links but it is about communication in between a java application and android but i want to communicate between only two android devices connected to a same wifi network.

Comment: May i know area of this WIFI..means within 10 metre or 20 meter.

Comment: Please take a look at this http://mason.gmu.edu/~jsuh4/impact/Handshake_Problem%20teaching.pdf

Comment: @BlueGreen it is 10 meter.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this using XMPP. Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP) is a communications protocol for message-oriented middleware based on XML.
For your implementation, you can setup an XMPP server like [openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/). You can find a tutorial to setup openfire [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=64eO7yaWeWQ). To write your clients you can use the `smack API` (for java clients) and `asmack API` (for android). A sample `asmack` based XMPP android client can be found [here](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Building-a-Chat-Application). Install this application in your android phones and you can communicate between the phones(send instant messages) using the same. You can also download `spark` client to test your application.

Comment: can i do it by using simple socket API of java i referred this link [link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-sercerclient-example-client.html)

but here i can connect between two android devices directly ,but i want to connect to another android device through a Access point which is a d-link router,and thats where i am stuck..Thanks

Comment: What Im able to understand is that you want your phones to be in the same wifi network. There are number of approaches to this problem. I have explained one and it will solve your problem. Install the openfire server on your machine and install the app I mentioned on your phones. Make sure all the devices are connected to your wifi network(your access point). You can communicate between your phones through openfire server.

Answer (score 0):

I have two apps, Server and Client
I installed server app on Mobile1 and client on Mobile2.
Mobile1 has mobile hotspot on. Mobile 2 is connected to MObile1 hotspot.
Mobile1 ip address is 100.109.213.12 and Mobile2 ip address is 192.168.43.33

I used this code: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-send-data-through-wifi-in-android-programmatically

Connection happens but data transfer is not working.

I couldn't change ip address of phone with mobile hotspot on but for Mobile2, I was able to change wifi to static ip but after that even client is not getting connected to server, which was working earlier.

Can I do data transfer by switching mobile hotspot on one phone and connecting another phone as client to the hotspot and then running client and server apps on these two phones. I am not going to use any 3rd device such as a router.

Comment: Welcome aboard! This appears to be a new question, rather than an answer. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask